# Trying to SUM total time between events WHERE current timestamp needs to be subtracted from the next

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First time post. Please be kind.

Have a DB table with "ID", "State", & "TimeStamp".
The "State" number represents the current condition of a machine in my factory. i.e. 100=stopped, 130=running, 170=faulted, etc, etc.
Every time the state number changes, a new record is inserted.
This works well and gives me an entry with the State number and an associated time stamp.
The duration of time that the machine was in a particular state could be found by subtracting the timestamp for a given record from the timestamp for the next record (when the state changes).

So far I've used the LEAD function to get the timestamp of the next row and place it beside the preceding row. Visually this "looks" like a start: if I subtracted the two timestamp columns I could get a time difference. If I had the difference I could SUM for each instance of each different State number.

```
SELECT
        [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State],
        [t_stamp],
        LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime 
FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN '2019-04-17 13:00' AND '2019-04-17 14:00'
```

Ultimately what I want is a report to show a pie chart. Each section of the pie will represent the cumulative amount of time the machine was in each given state. e.g. in State 130 for 5hr43min, in State 170 for 56min, etc. etc...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What is your question? You explained the data but not what you need help with.

Comment: I think you just don't know about the DATADIFF function -- is that what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have done all the hard work you can now use a sub query and DATEDIFF to get what you want:

```
SELECT  [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State], DATEDIFF(mi,[t_stamp],NextStateTime) TimeInState
FROM 
(
  SELECT
        [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State],
        [t_stamp],
        LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime 
  FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
  WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN '2019-04-17 13:00' AND '2019-04-17 14:00'
) SQ
```

Answer (score 0):

And to aggregate the cumulative amount of time per machine state:

```
with a as (
    SELECT
        [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State],
        HowLong = datediff(
            minute,
            [t_stamp],
            LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (
                ORDER BY
                    [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx] 
            )
        )
    FROM
        [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
    WHERE
        [t_stamp] BETWEEN '2019-04-17 13:00'
        AND '2019-04-17 14:00'
)
select
    Machine_State,
    CumulativeTime = sum(HowLong)
from
    a
group by
    Machine_State
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks all for the quick response. Really helpful!
Just by way of background, I'm no SQL expert (probably just a novice really) so your help is much appreciated.

Code offered by Chris worked well to get the total time for each row.

With the code from Michael I had a tiny little problem at the end of the ORDER BY clause just after the LEAD function.

I then combined both code sample and got it to work.

```
--my version...
  WITH StateTimes AS
  (
    SELECT
        [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State],
        DATEDIFF(second, [t_stamp], NextStateTime) AS TimeInState
    FROM
      (
      SELECT
            [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
            [Machine_State],
            [t_stamp],
            LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]) NextStateTime
      FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
      WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN '2019-04-17 13:00' AND '2019-04-17 14:00'
      ) SQ --"SQ" denotes the sub-query (in the brackets)
  )
  SELECT
    [Machine_State],
    CumulativeTime = SUM(TimeInState)
  FROM
    StateTimes
  GROUP BY
    [Machine_State]
```

Thanks again guys!
I'm sure you'll hear from me again soon...

Comment: I forgot to remove the NextStateTime alias 